# WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT in wp-config.php seems to be ignored

Tags: wordpress

I am using **WordPress v.3.8.1** with WMPL (WordPress Multilingual Plugin) v.3.1.4 and WPML Media Pugin v.2.1.3.

In php.ini file I have...

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

I already have a info.php file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` where I can see that `memory_limit = 512M`.

In wp-config.php file I have before wp-settings.php inclusion...

```
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '384M' );
```

When I am trying to use "Media Translation" I get this error after 50/400 media have been processed...

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in /wp-includes/plugin.php on line 1939
```

I am sorry for the duplicate https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/137698/45047 but I really need some guidelines.

Thank you!

Comment: I have contacted my hosting provider and he told me that he hasn't put a limit to RAM - default is 128MB - so from the error message I can see that I am already over default.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make it same on both files.

1. in php.ini
2. in wp_config.php

after this just reboot your server(if you have access).

Comment: I don't understand why it has to be the same in both files (I guess you mean `define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );`). Anyways I have done that with **no result**. Also if you use this `SetEnv PHPRC /location/todir/containing/phpinifile` in root's .htaccess you don't have to reboot the server.

Answer (score 0):

Just send email to your hosting provider and he will change it also you must have same limit in php.ini and config.php, just send email to your provider and he will reebot your server..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I wrote (see comment above) I am already over the server's limit. So I think the error would say "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of **134217728 bytes** exhausted (tried to allocate 134741528 bytes) in /wp-includes/plugin.php on line 1939"

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue with uploading and I found that on php.ini you have also to change the filesize_limit, which by default is set to 2M, you will find this on the lines 920 - 922 :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
;http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
 upload_max_filesize=64M
```

You can change the number as it's pleases you.